# Return first instance of capturing group if found, otherwise empty string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

My inputs are strings that may or may not contain a pattern:

```
p = '(\d)'
s = 'abcd3f'
```

I want to return the capturing group for the first match of this pattern if it is found, and an empty string otherwise.

```
result = re.search(p, s)[1]
```

Will return the first match. But if `s = 'abcdef'` then `search` will return `None` and the indexing will throw an exception. Instead of doing that, I'd like it to just return an empty string. I can do:

```
g = re.search(p, s)

result = ''
if len(g) > 0: result = g[1]
```

Or even:

```
try:
    result = re.search(p, s)[1]
except:
    result = ''
```

But these both seem pretty complicated for something so simple. Is there a more elegant way of accomplishing what I want, preferably in one line?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `if YourString is None:` to accomplish that. For example:

```
if s is None : s = ''
```

Example for Python:

```
import re
m = re.search('(\d)', 'ab1cdf')
if m is None : m = ''
print m.group(1)
```